# How to prevent Kendo MultiSelect from losing values after editing in a grid template?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I have a grid that displays a comma-separated list of values, and it has an array that gets used in a template editor for the grid. (On the server, I transform the comma-separated list to an array for the Kendo multiselect AngularJS directive). I have almost everything working: display, edit, and adding values in the multiselect.

There's just one weird thing happening: after I add a value in the multiselect, click Save in the editor, and reopen the editor, the multiselect *then* only displays one of the most-recently entered values. I know that the values are there and going through the pipeline, because the values make it into the database. I can refresh the page, open the editor, and all the values display in the multiselect correctly, including the one I just added.

It's as if kendo "forgets" most of the values when I reopen the editor. **How can this be prevented?** Does the MultiSelect need to be rebound to the values? If so, how?

I have tried adding [this onChange event](https://www.telerik.com/forums/lost-selected-items-after-rebind), but it had no effect. I've [added valuePrimitive](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/multiselect/how-to/AngularJS/keep-view-and-model-in-sync) to no effect. I tried specifying k-rebind, but it caused an error.

Here's the directive being used in the `text/x-kendo-template`:

```
        <select kendo-multi-select
                id="zipCode"
                k-placeholder="'Enter zip codes...'"
                style="width: 225px"
                k-on-change="dataItem.dirty=true"
                k-auto-bind="false"
                k-min-length="3"
                k-enforce-min-length="true"
                k-data-source="options.zipCodeDataSource"
                k-data-text-field="'text'"
                k-filter="'startsWith'"
                k-filtering="options.zipCodeFiltering"
                k-no-data-template="'...'"
                k-ng-model="dataItem.zipArray"
                k-highlight-first="true" />
```

And this is the DataSource:

```
options.zipCodeDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    severFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: serviceUrl + "ZipCode/Get",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: jsonType,
            data: function (e) {
                // get your widget.
                let widget = $('#zipCode').data('kendoMultiSelect');
                // get the text input
                let filter = widget.input.val();
                // what you return here will be in the query string
                return {
                    filter: filter
                };
            }
        },
    },
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "Count",
        model:
        {
            id: "text",
            fields: {
                text: { editable: false, defaultValue: 0 },
            }
        },
        parse: function (response) {
            return response;
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
    }
});
```

If I display `{{dataItem.zipArray}}` in a `<pre>` all of the expected values *are* there.

I wonder if something needs to be added to the edit event handler in the kendo grid definition, but I'm not sure what it would be. I've had to do binding like that for the dropdownlist directive.

```
    edit: function (e) {

        if (e.model.marketId === 0) {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Add");
        } else {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Edit");
        }

        // re-bind multi-select here??

        // These two lines actually cause the multiselect to lose pre-existing items in dataItem.zipArray
        // var multiselect = kendo.widgetInstance(angular.element('#zipCode'));
        // multiselect.trigger('change');
    }
```

...

**Update:**

[This dojo demonstrates the issue](http://dojo.telerik.com/IREVAXar).

1. Run the dojo
2. Edit the first record in the Contracts grid
3. Add a zip code such as 22250
4. Click Save
5. Then click Edit on the first row again
6. Only zip code 22250 is displayed in the editor

Also, I notice that if I change `k-min-length="3"` to `k-min-length="1"`, then the issue goes away. But in the scenario I'm working on, it needs to be `3`.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for your issue?

Comment: @Sajeetharan See the Update above http://dojo.telerik.com/IREVAXar

Comment: did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with kendo itself. Back then this issue was reported **[`here.`](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1473)**

Ok based on the reply from telerik, this issue has been fixed in 2017 R3 SP1 release (2017.3.1018). You can verify it by using this updated dojo example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/IREVAXar/3

Comment: could you offer the bounty ? :P

Comment: They already took the bounty and it expired. Otherwise I would. Note that between the 2016.3.914 version of Kendo and the 2017.3.1018 version, they changed the auto-complete directive so that it no longer deals with arrays and only works with strings. In the application I'm working on, I changed some of the auto-completes to combo-boxes as a workaround. This shows how to make the combo-box function like an auto-complete http://jsfiddle.net/CxSRQ/409/